# Display Last Modified Date of web page using Apache modules and Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, apache

How do I get last modified date of a file using the HTML DOM lastModified Property. At present, the code I have returns the present date. From reading other posts I see that this is because either:

A)The document is indeed being modified on-load due to JS DOM manipulation etc

and/or

B) I need to adjust apache server configs to return information in the header that document.lastModified can use to display the last-mod date instead of current date.

How do I use mod_expires or some other module to do this?
-or-
Can I somehow use the SSI directive:

```
<!--#flastmod virtual="$DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

to retrieve the info and capture it via javascript for use somewhere else in page.

I do not want to have to place in every location I want to show it, but rather use it in a globally included footer or header and then use javascript/jQuery to dynamically render the last modified date in various other html elements.

Here is the code I am using now, I hope this helps show how I plan to implement in in the html:

```
$(function() {
var x = new Date(document.lastModified);
var frmt_options = {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit"
};
var xy = x.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", frmt_options);
$('h1.template').append("<span>Last Modified: " + xy + "</span>");
$('h2.main_category').append("<span>Last Modified:<br>" + xy + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried this and it seems to work. This also includes cross-browser friendly formatting for the date that works in IE, FF, Safari and Chrome.( formatting solution in the above answer breaks in IE and Safari).
Put in global header:

```
<span class="lastmod"> This file last modified 
<!--#config timefmt="%B %e, %Y - %I:%M%p" -->   
<!--#echo var="LAST_MODIFIED" -->
</span>
```

js:

```
var lm= $('.lastmod').text()
    $('h1.template').append(lm);
```